# Clearing out junk tracking data from old versions of Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, tracking-extract

Is there a way of clearing out old tracking data from Journey Builder tracking? We have taken several versions of a journey and the old entries for each send stack up beneath it. Is there any way to delete these? Image for reference:
[image]